# How To Allocate Contiguous and Fixed Memory in .NET Core

Tags: c#, memory-management, .net-core

I am working on a physics simulation project where performance is critical, and I think one bottleneck is my memory management.  Currently, I have buffer objects that contain a fixed number of rigid bodies, particles and forces.  All of the physics entities are initialized within its buffer before the simulation starts.  When an entity is needed, the first inactive one is selected, otherwise, the oldest, and when it is no longer needed, it is moved to the end, so the active entities are all front packed.

Here is the data structure that I am using.

```
public sealed class Buffer<TValue> : IEnumerable<BufferElement<TValue>> where TValue : new()
{
    public Buffer(int capacity)
    {
        Count = 0;
        Capacity = capacity;
        Elements = new BufferElement<TValue>[capacity];

        for (var index = 0; index < Elements.Length; index++)
        {
            Elements[index] = new BufferElement<TValue>();
        }
    }

    public int Count { get; private set; }

    public int Capacity { get; private set; }

    private int ActiveCount { get; set; }

    private BufferElement<TValue>[] Elements { get; }

    public BufferElement<TValue> Activate()
    {
        if (Count == ActiveCount) Count = 0;

        var bufferElement = Elements[Count++];

        if (!bufferElement.Active)
        {
            bufferElement.Active = true;
            ActiveCount++;
        }

        return bufferElement;
    }

    public void Deactivate(BufferElement element)
    {
        if (!element.Active) return;

        element.Active = false;

        var lhs = element.Index;
        var rhs = --ActiveCount;

        Elements[lhs] = Elements[rhs];
        Elements[rhs] = element;

        Elements[lhs].Index = lhs;
        Elements[rhs].Index = rhs;
    }
}
```

After reading up on how .NET Core treats arrays, there are two things that might be an issue.  The first is each time you access an element in the array, it performs safety checks, and the second being that the GC can copy the array to a new memory address.

I would like to have all of my buffers that contain physics entities to not preform any safety checks and to be fixed in contiguous memory, if possible. I believe this should be possible, since the size of each buffer is fixed, and the size of the elements (rigid body, particle, force) are fixed as well.

There seems to be many ways of managing memory in C#, and I am having a difficult time figuring out which would be right for me in this situation.

- [Pointer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/pointer-types)
- [Marshal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal?view=netcore-3.0)
- [Memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memory-1?view=netcore-3.0)

Now, the question boils down to three parts:

1. Can this be done?
2. If so, what is the best method to manage memory?
3. And, what would the proper implementation look like?

Comment: Consider looking into c#'s Span<T>. This is a thread safe wrapper for arrays in c# that is highly performant. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVWQRbqcXJ4

Comment: In my case, should I use Memory<T> then? The simulation is long running, so it will occupy more than one stack frame.  If I am understanding it correctly, Span<T> is meant for allocating space on the stack, which is disposed when the execution leaves the context.

Comment: You can allocate it in static space so it doesn't go out of scope and get disposed.

Comment: Is there a reason to use Span<T> over Memory<T>?

Comment: Have you considered to use a gpu?

Comment: I have not considered using the GPU.  Are you referring to storing the entities on the GPU, or do you mean leveraging the GPU to do the simulation?

Comment: The _array_ is laid out in contiguous memory.  The **contents** probably are not: Since you're modifying `BufferElement` I'm assuming it's a class, at which point the array will contain pointers, not the element itself.  I'm unclear if structs will be laid directly into an array, but if so it would most likely be under similar constraints to the direct copy optimizations.  Sequential layout is only helpful if you perform a sufficient amount of work (proportionally) over sequential elements - this is much easier if elements are laid directly into the array.

Comment: That is a good point.  `BufferElement` is indeed a class, so, you are correct, the array would be a contiguous block of memory containing the pointers.  Since the physics entities are constantly being iterated over, having them sequentially in memory would definitely cause less cache misses.  Do you know how to make sure the contents of an array are contiguous as well?

Comment: Your `Activate`/`Deactivate` pair has issues - `Activate` seems to assume that elements will be accessed as if it's a standard circular buffer (which probably exists for .NET, as well as standard object pools), but `Deactivate` acts like it's in a linked list.  Given what I presume are bugs in `Activate`, your desire to avoid array bounds checks does not fill me with confidence (for instance, what if `capacity` is set to 1?  Why do you reset to 0 every time you reach the active count? What happens if an element is already active?).

Comment: @Jedi_Maseter_Sam - They're in heap space, so you'd need a custom allocator, which is considered an (somewhat) advanced topic in C/C++ land, and most likely impossible in C#.

Comment: _If I am understanding it correctly, Span<T> is meant for allocating space on the stack_  Not quite.  `Span<T>` is a ref struct so the span itself is allocated on the stack, but the span can point to [managed memory, native memory, or memory managed on the stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=netcore-3.0).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse ignore the bugs, I accidentally copied from an older branch.  I will fix it when I get back on my computer.  In regards to the memory allocation, does `Marshal` not allocate contiguous memory?

Comment: @FrankBoyne If I need the collection to be long living, does it make more sense to use a static `Span<T>` like what was suggested above, or does `Memory<T>` makes more sense?  Also, do you happen to know if either of those use range checks, of if that is only avoidable using `unsafe` with pointers?

Comment: Most of the methods in `Marshal`, from a quick look, will involve a copy, which is maybe worse for you (since you'd be copying back and forth).  You'd need to overlay a view into raw memory, somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, yes, it can be done. Second, the *best* really depends, since many tradeoffs exist, and this quickly becomes an *opinionated* post. Third, the lightest alternative would be to use the `fixed` keyword to allocate your array in an `unsafe` context (no safety checks on arrays neither in here and allows you to use C style pointers) and pin its address so that it doesn't change, although using `Span` or `Memory` might be easier, the low level approach of `fixed` and `unsafe` can yield better performance when used correctly. Check out [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement#targetText=The%20fixed%20statement%20is%20only,only%20in%20a%20fixed%20context.), it's the official docs and it's filled with neat examples. One last tip, try to switch to a `struct` instead *if it's possible*, they have no memory overhead and higher memory density, yielding much better cache access times since many more will fit in the cache.

Comment: If you have an array of `struct`, does't the accessor copy the value?  The reason I used a class is because rigid body, particle and force can have one to many relationships, and I was working on the assumption that having a reference to an object would be faster.  I assume if I were to use structs, I would need to store an array of pointer to elements instead of an array of elements?  Lastly, wouldn't `.Pin()` in `Memory<T>` suffice instead of using `fixed`?

Comment: That's why I said *"if it's possible"*. However, an array of `struct` is passed as a reference. Arrays are reference types even if they contain value types. Furthermore, remember you can use the `ref` keyword to pass a reference to a value type and avoid copying.

Comment: Yes it would, but `Span` and `Memory` are higher level than `fixed` and `unsafe`. I thought you wanted as much raw performance and control as possible.

Comment: I meant accessing the array like, `array[index]`, would yield a copy of the value at index. Also, I did not know you could return a `ref` from a function, I thought that was only applicable to inbound parameters.

Comment: I guess the thing I do not get about `fixed` is where you should put it.  If you place it in the constructor and set a field within the `fixed` statement, won't the GC still have control over the memory?

Comment: @Jedi_Maseter_Sam "meant accessing the array like, `array[index]`, would yield a copy of the value at index"????? Can you please clarify why you believe so? (assuming you are talking about "array" as array in C# and not array as `List<T>`)

Comment: `public static void Main()
{
        var values = new Value[1];
        var references = new[] {new Reference()};

        var value = values[0];
        var reference = references[0];

        value.Id = 1;
        reference.Id = 1;

        Console.WriteLine(values[0].Id == value.Id);
        Console.WriteLine(references[0].Id == reference.Id);
}

public struct Value
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
 }

 public class Reference
 {
        public int Id { get; set; }
 }`

Comment: The GC will have control of the memory, `fixed` indicates to the GC that a particular variable cannot be moved to another memory location. As of C# 7 there is a feature called `ref return`, and you can pass `ref array[index]` to a method with an inbound `ref` and that particular value is passed by reference.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It seems that the most practical approach would be to use `ref return` so I can use `struct` instead of `class`, and also use `Memory<T>` to pin the data. I know it might not perform as well as using `fixed`, but I think from a pragmatic point of view, nesting the `fixed` statements will not be scalable.  Each of those types I listed in the original post have many child types that perform different tasks, so they all need a separate buffer.